# what is the difference between alias_method and alias_method_chain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, alias-method, alias-method-chain

I was working on my web-application and I wanted to override a method for example if the original class is

```
class A
  def foo
    'original'
  end
end
```

I want to override foo method  it can be done like this

```
class A
  alias_method :old_foo, :foo
  def foo
    old_foo + ' and another foo'
  end
end
```

and I can call both old and new methods like this

```
obj = A.new
obj.foo  #=> 'original and another foo'
obj.old_foo #=> 'original'
```

so what is the use of alias_method_chain if I can access and keep both methods like the way I did ?

Answer (score 9):

`alias_method_chain` behaves different than `alias_method`

If you have method `do_something` and you want to override it, keeping the old method, you can do:

```
alias_method_chain :do_something, :something_else
```

which is equivalent to:

```
alias_method :do_something_without_something_else, :do_something
alias_method :do_something, :do_something_with_something_else
```

this allows us to easily override method, adding for example custom logging. Imagine a `Foo` class with `do_something` method, which we want to override. We can do:

```
class Foo
  def do_something_with_logging(*args, &block)
    result = do_something_without_logging(*args, &block)
    custom_log(result)
    result
  end
  alias_method_chain :do_something, :logging
end
```

So to have your job done, you can do:

```
class A
  def foo_with_another
    'another foo'
  end
  alias_method_chain :foo, :another
end
a = A.new
a.foo # => "another foo"
a.foo_without_another # => "original"
```

Since it isn't very complicated, you can also do it with plain `alias_method`:

```
class A
  def new_foo
    'another foo'
  end
  alias_method :old_foo, :foo
  alias_method :foo, :new_foo
end
a = A.new
a.foo # => "another foo"
a.old_foo # => "original"
```

For more information, you can refer [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Module/alias_method_chain).

Comment: This is a good explanation for `alias_method_chain` but i think the question is a little bit different.

Comment: Thanks ,but this is what alias_method_chain done , what i'm asking is if I can do it with alias_method like my example  what is the real difference then between the two ways ?

Comment: @user1651643 if you want to preserve `old_foo` name to the 'old' method, then no, you can't do it with `alias_method_chain`.

Comment: @MarekLipka that's mean that there are no differences between the two ways and alias_method_chain doesn't add new things ?

Comment: @helsayed yes. All `alias_method_chain` is doing in this case is `alias_method :foo_without_another, :foo` and `alias_method :foo, :foo_with_another`.